# fail2ban - virtual host specific

Tags: fail2ban

Is it possible to set up fail2ban to ban ip addresses only for certain virtualhost? For example I have a filter that detects various attempts to run *.php file inside website structure. Which I would like to ban. I have multiple websites on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Fail2ban bans IP addresses on the firewall. Virtualhosts are defined on the HTTP / SSL level on the protocol stack, while the Linux firewall works only on the IP / TCP level.

So, the firewall doesn't know anything about virtualhosts, and whether to allow traffic or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could seperate your logfiles in the apache viritualhosts definition.
Then you can tell fail2ban to only regard these specific logfiles:

e.g.

1) Edit apache2 Virtualhost definition Logpaths:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.foo.com

  # if you want this vhost to listen to extra names, uncomment the next line
  # ServerAlias foo.com www.bar.com bar.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.foo.com/htdocs

  CustomLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

2) Edit your Fail2ban jail.local settings:

Configure Fail2ban as you like it. Here are some good examples: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04

For the example Virtualhost above your logpath in jail.local should look like:

```
logpath  = /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-*.log
```

Comment: Hi, not sure if I understand. From your advice as far I understand it - it is just about separating the logs, which I already have. However, if an ip gets banned, it would be banned for whole server, for all webpages on it, right? That is what I try to avoid.

Comment: OK now i got it. I guess that's not possible with fail2ban. The way to block and allow people per virtual host is the "allow,deny from" directive in the virtual host definition.